# Add new data to table (ASP.NET Web API)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Web API project.

I this project I have table

Here is table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeTable] (
[Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Company]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[INN]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[StartDay]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[StartPause] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[EndDay]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[EndPause]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

And here is class:

```
 public partial class TimeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string INN { get; set; }
    public string StartDay { get; set; }
    public string StartPause { get; set; }
    public string EndDay { get; set; }
    public string EndPause { get; set; }
}
```

App will send in first request `Company`, `INN` and `StartDay` data. 
In second `Company`, 'INN' and `StartPause` data.

First I need to check if `company` and  `inn` exists, if not write data to table.

I can do this like this

```
public IHttpActionResult PostTimeTable(TimeTable timeTable)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }



        db.TimeTables.Add(timeTable);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = timeTable.Id }, timeTable);
    }
```

But if data exists I need to select row with `Company` = `timeTable.Company` and `INN` = `time.Table.INN`

I try to it Like here for Company first

```
.Where(x=>x.Company = timeTable.Company)
```

But I have error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'   trackingappbackend  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\trackingappbackend\trackingappbackend\Controllers\StartPausesController.cs 84  Active

How I can do this?

Comment: do you really need `nvarchar (max)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `==` when checking for a condition:

```
.Where(x => x.Company == timeTable.Company && x.INN == timeTable.INN)
```